# Number of elements in $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $A^{p-1}=\mathbb{1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came up with the following question

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field of order $p$ a prime number. Let $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ be the group of $2×2$ matrices with entries over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $det(A)=1$. Determine the number of elements $A$ of $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $A^{p-1}=\mathbb{1}$.

I know what the order of $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is, but that extra condition is what causes me trouble. Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Such a matrix is diagonalizable. If the two eigenvalues are the same then it is $\alpha I$. If the two eigenvalues are distinct then $A$ is defined by its two eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A$ such that $A^{p-1}=1$ has minimal polynomial dividing $X^{p-1}-1$. This polynomial factorizes as $\prod_{0\neq a\in F_p}(X-a)$, since all the non-zero elements of $F_p$ have are $(p-1)$th roots of unity. it follows that the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $F_p$ and has simple roots. We thus see that $A$ is diagonalizable.

If $A$ has two equal eigenvalues, then it is a multiple of the identity, and it is easy to count such matrices.

If $A$ has two different eigenvalues, then it is conjugate to a matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ with $a\neq b$. it is not difficult to find the centralizer of such a  matrix and deduce from that the order of its conjugacy class. Alternatively, $A$ is determined by a tuple $(U,V,a,b)$ of two linearly independent $1$-dimensional subspaces of $F_p^2$ and two different elements of $F_p$: you can also count such tuples easily.

Sum everything and you got your answer.

Comment: Wow! Totally didnt expect the eigenvalues to show up, thanks! :D